# Easiest Way to build a simple, form-based Python Frontend?

Tags: python, framework, user-interface

In have already setup a Database and an API (via FastAPI), at the moment running on my local system.

So when i send a POST-request with a respective Body,Events are created and written to the Database. This works just fine.

Next I want to develop a Frontend some simple Features:

- A Calendar showing at what times there are events
- A Form that allows specifying the "Event" Parameters and by clicking "Submit Event" triggers the API
- An Overview Page, showing Details for Events

So my tasks are quite simple. I already looked at some Python Frameworks, but as far as I can seet it did not match my needs:

**Django** seemed a bit like an overkill, as it comes with its own Database.

I did not want to use **Flask** as I wanted to try out FastAPI and to me it occured strange to have two apps that do routing.

I am also somewhat familiar with **Dash** by plotly, but as it is more for graphs and dashboarding, it seemed like a workaround for me to use it for my application.

What is the recommendation in my case? Or should stick with either of the frameworks mentioned above? As this is the first time I am developing a complete application (DB+Backend+Frontend) so I kind of got stuck with this question.

Comment: I have struggled with a similar dilemma for far too long and finally settled on flask framework. I will watch this question with interest to see if there is any useful suggestions but sadly my own past experience on the subject doesn't bring much optimism to the table.

Comment: I ended up using dash. It can do far more than just dashboards with plots.